# Error using a variable declared in _AppStart VB

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I'm working with ASP Web Pages, in Visual Studio 2012. Im starting to make some test and one of those test ois to have global/sitewide variables used in files in the website project.
The problem is that i cant and get an error when using the declared variable in a file on the project. Probably im missing something or i'm making a mistake.

The Code i have is the following
File: _AppStart.vbhtml (is in the root of my website)

```
@Code
'Declaring Global Variables for the Application
Dim sitename As String  = "Test Razor App"
```

End Code

File: App_Layout/defaultTheme/_header.vbhtml

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
'<title>@sitename</title>
'<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

If i use the @sitename i get the error: 'sitename' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. If i use a text the project runs perfectly.

Im following the basic tutorial in http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/webpages_global.asp

Any Help will be Good. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the tutorial found here: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/working-with-pages/18-customizing-site-wide-behavior

To set a global variable you would store it in the AppState dictionary:

```
@Code
 'Declaring Global Variables for the Application
 AppState("sitename") = "Test Razor App"
End Code
```

More info on AppState: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.helperpage.appstate(v=vs.111).aspx

Then you would use it in your pages as follows:

```
<title>@AppState("sitename")</title>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks for the help, i replaced as suggested and now is working good.